# RSelenium - Como clicar no check-box e então no botão submit

Tags: r, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Estou tentando fazer um web scraping do site do Banco Central. Para isso, preciso selecionar um item do menu drop-down, então marcar um check box e então clicar no botão de submit.

Mas quando eu tento clickar no check-box, não acontece nada. E eu não consigo encontrar o botão de submit.

Meu código

```
library(magrittr)

driver <- RSelenium::rsDriver(browser="firefox", port=4545L, verbose=F) 
remote_driver <- driver[["client"]]
remote_driver$navigate("https://www.bcb.gov.br/estabilidadefinanceira/encontreinstituicao")
Sys.sleep(3) 

tableElem <- remote_driver$findElement(using = "xpath", value = "//div[@class = 'container main']//iframe")
remote_driver$switchToFrame(tableElem)

remote_driver$findElement(using = "id", value = "segmento")
option <- remote_driver$findElement(using = 'xpath', "//select[@id='segmento']/option[@value='object:78']")
option$clickElement()

# Não acontece nada
relo <- remote_driver$findElement(using = "id", value = "incluirInstituicoesPesquisa")
relo$clickElement()

# Não encontro o botão Pesquisar
pesq <- remote_driver$findElement(using = "class", value = "btn btn-primary")
pesq$clickElement()
```

[Site](https://www.bcb.gov.br/estabilidadefinanceira/encontreinstituicao)

O check box que eu quero marcar é o  "Incluir instituições em regime especial e liquidação ordinária".
O botão que eu quero clickar é o "Pesquisar".

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui.

Só substituir a parte que não funciona por:

```
relo <- remote_driver$findElement(using = "xpath", value = "/html/body/section/div/div/ui-view/section/div/div[1]/form/div[8]/label")

relo$clickElement()

pesq <- remote_driver$findElement(using = "xpath", value = "/html/body/section/div/div/ui-view/section/div/div[1]/form/div[9]/button[1]")
pesq$clickElement()
```

Clicando com o botão direito em cima da área e indo em "Inspecionar elemento", na área "Inspetor" da pra copiar o xpath certinho.